# How to use batch insert in node jdbc module with teradata

Tags: node.js, jdbc

I am trying to insert huge data to `teradata` database from my `node.js` application.
I have an array of insert statement. I need to insert them as a batch. please help.

Note: I am looking for something like below that I used in java program

```
statement.addBatch(query);
statement.executeBatch();
```

But I couldn't find any in the jdbc npm module.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need and looked at the [jdbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) and [nodejdbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejdbc) packages, and neither offered support for JDBC's batch update methods.  I ended-up adding them to the Promise-based nodejdbc package and submitted a pull request with the changes.

**Update** [nodejdbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejdbc) maintainer accepted the PR, and batch support is now part of the package!

Example (ES6 used):

```
theDb.getConnection().then(conn => {
  return conn.prepareStatement('insert into TEST values (?,?)')
}).then(pstmt => {
  for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, i);
    pstmt.setString(2, `num${i}`);
    pstmt.addBatchSync();
  }
  return pstmt.executeBatch();
}).then(rowsUpdated => {
  console.log('rows update:', rowsUpdated);
}).catch(error => console.error('error occurred during batch insert', error));
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this. I guess i need to switch from jdbc to nodejdbc. but again nodejdbc doesn't support connection pooling.